# How to add single element in JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html:

```
<div class="register-form-box">
    <label>Name :</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" onblur="return validateForm(this)" data-lv-msg="Please enter your name" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function validateForm(field){
 if(!field.value.trim()){
  var msg = field.getAttribute("data-lv-msg");
  $(field).after('<div class="error_message">'+msg+'</div>');
  field.focus();
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

The Code above is working fine. But the error message`<div class="error_message">Please enter your name</div>` is repeated.

What to change to only add it once?

Comment: Change it here: `onblur="validateForm(this)"` The `return` is causing it to be called twice.

Comment: you could create the `<div class="error_message">` in your html, set the `visibility: none;`, and in the jQuery code you could set the `visibility: visible;`

Comment: .show() and.hide is a better choice since jQuery is present

Answer (score 3):

This is a better solution in my opinion

```js
$(function() {
  $("input.required").on("blur",function() {
    $(this).next().toggle($.trim($(this).val())=="");
  });
});
```

```css
 .error { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="register-form-box">
  <label>Name :</label>
  <input name="name" class="required" type="text"/><span class="error">Please enter your name</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all `.error_message`s before adding them:

```
function validateForm(field){
 $(".error_message").remove();
 if(!field.value.trim()){
  var msg = field.getAttribute("data-lv-msg");
  $(field).after('<div class="error_message">'+msg+'</div>');
  field.focus();
  return false;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code little bit so that you can achieve what you want

Before inserting error_message div just check whether it is already there.
If its not there then only insert the div

You can use $(".error_message").length to check whether the div is presented or not.

**code snippet:**

```
function validateForm(field){
 if(!field.value.trim()){
  var msg = field.getAttribute("data-lv-msg");
  if(!$(".error_message").length)
   $(field).after('<div class="error_message">'+msg+'</div>');
  field.focus();
  return false;
 }
}
```

---

### Update

If you want to use the error_message div for multiple input tags:

- give an id to input tag
- use sibling selector to check whether the div is presented or not
- You can use $("#name+.error_message").length for checking whether the div is existed or not.

[JSBIN Demo](http://jsbin.com/zitosexoyuje/1/edit)